# Bodyguard searching for alien "fountain of youth"

Tags: story-identification

I read a sci-fi story years ago about a man who is hired as a bodyguard for a trip to a planet that is rumored to have a "fountain of youth" It turns out to be the remains of an alien ship that could warp time as its propulsion.

I can't remember the name of the story. I thought it was by E C Tubb as the man is a lot like Earl Dumarest.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: You read it years ago? Please try to narrow it down. Was it more or less than 40 years ago? What sort of publication did you read it in—magazine or paperback or hardcover collection? In the US or the UK or some other country?

Comment: probably about 40 years ago

Answer (score 6):

Your memory served you well: there's a Dumarest story that deals with a "fountain of youth" (technically, it's a place that heals) which actually is a buried alien artifact.

It's the sixth book in the series, titled **Lallia** and published in 1971.
[Here's a detailed summary](http://jeffbuser.com/Dumarest/06Lallia.html) of the book.

> The Guardians, almost incomprehensibly alien, treat them as they would apparently treat any pilgrims.  Dumarest deduces the shrine is actually an alien artifact, but sees no harm in seeking its help.  The shrine heals their wounds and relieves their hunger and thirst.  More, it seems to sense what is “crippling” Dumarest: the loss of his homeworld.  It tries to “heal” him by calculating the position of earth to the best of its ability, presumably based on clues locked in his subconscious mind, details about his childhood journey away from Earth that he no longer remembers.